# Kafka Fails to Process all the messages - Java Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot application(spring version 2.2.2.RELEASE) where I have configured Kafka consumer which processes the data from Kafka and serves to multiple web sockets. The subscription is successful to kafka, but Not all messages from selected Kafka topic is processed by the consumer. Few messages are delayed and few are missed out. But the producer is sending out data which is perfectly ensured. Below I have shared the configuration properties that I have used.

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = kafkaBootstrapServer;
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
```

Is there any configuration I am missing?

Comment: How do you know the data is reaching the topic are you viewing it in in a UI?

Answer (score 3):

For a new Consumer (never committed offsets for the group.id) you must set `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET` to `earliest` to avoid missing any existing records in the topic (default is `latest`).

Comment: I don't need existing messages, but i need all the messages that will be sent from the moment i start the application. Will setting AUTO_OFFSET_RESET to earliest help in that case?

Comment: It won't make any difference if there is already a committed offset for the consumer `group.id`. It only applies the first time a `Consumer` starts (and until it commits at least one offset).

Comment: There is no other reason that a consumer will "miss" records.

Comment: Okay, I am doing some processing over the message, this processing takes like 4-5 seconds per message. In this case, until my processing is complete, will the next message be waiting to be processed? or it will be on another thread? is it a good idea to move this processing into a separate thread after consuming the message?

Comment: Assuming you are using spring-kafka, it depends on your concurrency settings and how many partitions are in the topic. All messages within the same partition will be processed on the same thread. You **must** process `max.poll.records` within `max.poll.interval.ms` to avoid a rebalance.